# How to lazy-load an Angular component from an html template?

Tags: html, angular, components, lazy-loading, angular2-template

I have an existing Angular app which eager-loads everything, and I would now like to add lazy-loading capabilities to it.

Lazy-loading routes works fine, especially by following the guidelines provided by https://link.medium.com/xJ18mitCElb and https://link.medium.com/8F3G2rg0slb, with the following routes construct in `AppRoutingModule`:

```
{path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: () => import('./dashboard/dashboard.module').then(m => m.DashboardModule)}
```

Programmatically loading components is also doable from the TypeScript code, by using a component factory, such as in https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/lazy-load-components-in-angular-596357ab05d8

However my application has multiple components which template embeds other components like:

component-a.html:

```
<h1>Title</h1>
<app-component-b></app-component-b>
<app-component-c></app-component-c>
```

Is it possible to have `app-component-b` and `app-component-c` lazy-loaded without changing significantly the existing html code of `component-a`? (So far, as they are not accessed via a route, lazy loading just does not happen).

Many thanks for any help and guidance!

Comment: How and when do you want lazy loading in angular components ? Can You spot more details ?

Comment: Thank you your help GRD! In the given example, I would like that when component-a is instantiated, it triggers the lazy-loading of child components app-component-b and app-component-c. component-a could either be itself lazy-loaded (because bound a lazy-loaded route), or eager-loaded (because it belongs to the root AppModule module). Does it clarify?

Comment: Are you on what version of angular currently using with this ?

Comment: Angular 10, but I could upgrade it useful!

Comment: If you add `<component-b> </component-b>` inside template of component-a then it is not lazy loading. Are you wanting to put component-b exactly at this place in template of component-a ?

Comment: Wow, looks great! I didn't test it yet on my side, but it seems to be a good solution. I am surprised to see that you don't even need to put cmp-b and cmp-c in a separate module. So they are lazy-loaded with a component granularity (instead of a module granularity)? Thank you so much!

Comment: Yes! If cmp-b and cmp-c are in seperate module, then inside cmp-a you have to use child router outlet with named outlet, and when cmp-a loads then you can navigate to child cmp with respeecetive named outlet, and in router config file cmp-b and cmp-c loads using loadChildren way too. This is another approach you can go with.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239858/discussion-between-grd-and-bfredo123).

Comment: Will you please help by supporting me https://www.buymeacoffee.com/grdtech and also I am available to work more. You can connect with me `grdtechlab@gmail.com` thank you @bfredo123